# NetBeans/Tomcat deployment problem

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans-6.9

When I tried to run my project in NetBeans 6.9, I got this error:

> Starting Tomcat process...
>
> Waiting for Tomcat...
>
> Tomcat server started.
>
> Incrementally deploying localhost:8084/hastaneBilgiSistemi
>
> Completed incremental distribution of localhost:8084/hastaneBilgiSistemi
>
> Incrementally redeploying localhost:8084/hastaneBilgiSistemi
>
> Deploy is in progress...
>
> deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FyakUP%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%
>   2Fcontext1397063015253659398.xml&path=/hastaneBilgiSistemi
>   Connection refused: connect
>
> C:\Users\yakUP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\hastaneBilgiSistemi\nbproject\build-impl.xml:688: The module has not been deployed.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 40 seconds)

How can I fix this?

Today I ve got same error

```
Incrementally deploying http://localhost:8084/hastaneBilgiSistemi
Completed incremental distribution of http://localhost:8084/hastaneBilgiSistemi
Incrementally redeploying http://localhost:8084/hastaneBilgiSistemi
Deploy is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FyakUP%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext163067119208813391.xml&path=/hastaneBilgiSistemi
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /hastaneBilgiSistemi but context failed to start
C:\Users\yakUP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\hastaneBilgiSistemi\nbproject\build-impl.xml:688: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I ve restarted Nb and pc . Problem didn't resolved. please help me

Answer (score 1):

Restart netbeans. I had a similar problem and worked for me.

Comment: li I said, I stayed one night trying to debug one similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a conflict in the library, I used 2 versions of slf4j. Both versions are conflicting if used together. So I removed the old one, did clean and build and ran the project again. It worked normally. No need to restart netbeans nor tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to specify what exactly causes NetBeans to fail, it can be a lot.

In any case, after building your application you can start Tomcat yourself by executing the startup script,

`<apache_tomcat_directory>/bin/startup.sh`

, and when Tomcat is up and running, deploy your application by pasting the .war to,

`<apache_tomcat_directory>/webapps`

That way will, first, allow you to continue your work and, second, to confirm the error is coming from NetBeans and not Tomcat instance itself.

p.s. NetBeans 6.9 is quite old, especially if u consider NetBeans has reached version 11.0 nowadays. I would suggest a NetBeans upgrade as well.